# Where can I get libcgroup and policycoreutils-python from on CentOS7?

Tags: centos, yum, centos7, package-management

I have a VM created from Vagrant `centos/7`.

I'm trying to [install docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/centos/), but it doesn't work. I tried with a SaltStack minion *and* just `vagrant ssh` and `sudo yum install`. But it tells me that it can't find these dependencies:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: docker-engine-1.9.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (docker_repo)
           Requires: libcgroup
Error: Package: docker-engine-selinux-1.9.1-1.el7.centos.noarch (docker_repo)
           Requires: policycoreutils-python
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I don't think either of the suggested solutions will do what I need. I've Googled around but all I get are links to rpmfind or rpmbone and sure, they may provide an rpm I could download but I'm pretty sure these *should* be in a repository somewhere.

`yum repolist` gives me this:

```
repo id                                                                  repo name                                                                                             status
docker_repo                                                              Docker Repository                                                                                        14
*epel/x86_64                                                             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                        8,842
extras/7/x86_64                                                          CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                                       278
repo-saltstack-el7                                                       SaltStack EL7 Repo                                                                                       92
updates/7/x86_64                                                         CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                                    1,726
repolist: 10,952
```

Comment: Exactly what sort of machine is this? The base repo seems to be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in centos base repository (not updates repository). You probably disabled it. Look at /etc/yum.repos.d/*   and set `enabled=1`

If you cannot find it, this is probably what you need (if you use stock hardware):

```
rpm -ivh http://mirror.centos.org/centos-7/7/os/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-7-1.1503.el7.centos.2.8.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: I think that `base` salt state somehow borked up the base CentOS repo state. I changed my salt state to have a different name `docker_repo` instead.